# Getting No such File or Directory Exception on Ubuntu when trying compile a java project from java.lang.Process

Tags: java

Recently, I have switched to Ubuntu v20.04 from Windows 10 Pro v2004 because of performance purposes. When, I was on Windows I can freely **compile a java project from another java program** by writing:

```
String pathToCompiler = "\"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-14/bin/javac\"";
Process compileProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToCompiler+" -d bin @.sources", null, new File("ProjectPath"))
```

### Where the sources file is a file containing the list of classes of the project

The code above works successfully on Windows 10.

- But On Linux(Ubuntu):
  if I substitute the value of variable `pathToCompiler` as
  `pathToCompiler = "\"/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac\""`
  the below exception is raised up and the program executing the command exits:

```
"/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac" -d bin  @.sources 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac"" (in directory "/home/arham/Documents/Omega Projects/Project0"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:416)
    at ide.utils.systems.BuildView.lambda$3(BuildView.java:267)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
```

`The problem is that the file actually exists but it says No Such File or Directory`
Actually, The program which is compiling the project is a Java IDE that I am creatiing.
**Someone please tell if he/she knows how to fix this bug**

[image: I have a screenshot of the error :(]

Comment: `new Process(...)` Did you create this "Process" class yourself? Can you share the code with us?

Comment: I forgot to write Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), Sorry! But I have corrected it now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Runtime.exec` method has [several problems](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) that make it difficult to use, and this is one of them. Use the [newer `ProcessBuilder` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.

```
String pathToCompiler = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-14/bin/javac";
Process compileProcess = new ProcessBuilder(pathToCompiler, "-d", "bin", "@.sources")
    .directory(new File("ProjectPath"))
    .start();
```

The differences are:

- Remove the extra quotes from around the path to the executable. If quoting is needed, the system takes care of it.
- Pass the each command line arguments as a separate string. This way you don't have to worry about quoting.

Comment: I am trying to do as you mentioned!

Comment: Thanks for help! But it is giving the same exception!

Comment: Is the exception *exactly* the same? Did you notice that you need to remove the extra quotes you have put around the path?

Comment: Sorry! But I did not removed the extra quotes, I am trying again

Comment: Thanks! Actually a Big Thanks for you! My IDE is working perfectly.

Comment: Can you tell me Please, now how will I mark this post as closed?

Comment: happy to help! It's better to leave the post open - that way you help future users who have a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

Update the path to the following:

```
String pathToCompiler = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac/";
```

Comment: Ok I am trying to add one slash at the end

Comment: Thanks for help! but it is giving the same exception